# How to check if all specific elements in a 2D Array have been selected? Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check if all "zero's" in my array have been selected/clicked on.
I've created two separate arrays:

1. the original array where you can't see the elements (need to be clicked on first) this is an int[][] array.
2. The clicked on array that shows the board with the elements that have been clicked on. This is a boolean[][] array.

I have tried various methods, the one shown below is the closest I've gotten.
But Java shows this as an error: "operator <= is undefined for argument type int, boolean". Gives error if I use == too.

```
private boolean win(int row, int col) {
    if(mazegame.board[row][col] = mazegame.clickedBoard[row][col]){
        return true;
    }

}
```

Have tried casting...but this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: One `=` is assignment, you need `==`. Also, your **and** condition appears identical to the first test.

Comment: Also you're checking the same thing twice

Comment: Ughh....yes...edited it and forgot to remove it....need a red bull, thank you for the advice

Comment: still gives the same error after fixing it though

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the piece of code that generates the error? You should look at [ask] and how to write a [MCVE]

Comment: Oh are you trying to compare an int to a boolean? That's not going to work. What does it mean for a number to be equal to a boolean?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm stuck on....thinking I should keep the mazegame.clickedBoard and get rid of mazegame.board....dunno.

Comment: You can't compare an int to a boolean. You can write an expression that says something like 'if i my int is such and such AND my boolean is whatnot, do x'. Which sounds like what you're trying to do. But you can't compare booleans and integers directly because booleans are not integers.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that...but when you're actually viewing all the classes for this thing it becomes a bit confusing - especially if you don't know what you need to do, you start trying stupid things because you're desperate. 0_o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will iterate through the elements in your board.

If the element is a `0`, it will check if the element at the same position in the clicked board is `true` (it has been clicked), if it is not, the loop will be interrupted and `false` will be returned.

If all zeroes are true in the corresponding clicked board, the loops will run through completely and the method will return `true`.

---

**Code:**

```
private boolean isSolved() {
  for(int i = 0; i < mazegame.board.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < mazegame.board[i].length; j++) {
      if(mazegame.board[i][j] == 0 && !mazegame.clickedBoard[i][j]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help, I really made a wrong turn thinking that I didn't need the two "for" statement and could replace them with mazegame.board[row][col].